# Minimal OS with less background process

Tags: linux, arch-linux, linux-kernel, linux-distributions

I am currently doing experiments on L1/L2/L3 cache. Measurement of L1/L2/L3 cache access time fully depends on where is my current data present, and that also depends on background process of OS running in parallel which forcefully evict my data from L1/L2 cache and influence the measurement.
So I need a LINUX OS where less background process is running along with OS, so that my data will get more space in cache OR my data will be in cache for more time.

**EDIT1 :**

Right now I am using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS version, but so many background process is there and that is influencing my outcome.

@ techie007 : I am trying to find access time of L1/L2/L3 cache and try to achieve the result as exact as per Intel document.

Which LINUX OS version should I go for ? Any NON-GUI LINUX ? or Any special OS ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "Questions seeking product, service, or learning material recommendations are off-topic because they become outdated quickly and attract opinion-based answers. Instead, describe your situation and the specific problem you're trying to solve. Share your research."

Comment: Use the one you like and stop/remove the background processes you don't want or need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe an extremely light Linux distribution such as [Damn Small Linux](http://www.damnsmalllinux.org/) would suit your needs.

Another option could be [Arch Linux](https://www.archlinux.org/) as it's build is well documented and you start with a very basic distribution.

You could then [disable all services](http://www.aboutlinux.info/2006/04/enabling-and-disabling-services-during_01.html) that are not required, thus making the OS footprint as small as you require.

Comment: thanks for answering. "disable all services" that are not required - means I need to figure it out. How to figure it out to find all services ? Using top command or anything else ?

Comment: I included a link to disabling services in my answer but a good place to start would be looking at the startup scripts in "/etc/init.d/".

Comment: Also look at [How do I prevent Linux services from auto-starting?](http://superuser.com/questions/203827/how-do-i-prevent-linux-services-from-auto-starting).

Comment: thanks @Geditdk. I will go with Arch linux . Will look into both the link you have provided.